# how to make feature vector from the lists

Tags: python, nltk

I'm new to python. Actually I have a train data which is in bag of words.Each line of the train data is an article. The labels of the train data is in another file and each i label is equal to i article in the train data. I did stemming on the train data and also removed the stop words. The output is the lists of words of each article(line). Now I want to extract a feature vector of it and then use it in my KNN classifier in python.. I don't know how to do it! I appreciate any quick answer.  Here's my code up to the things I did:

```
  import nltk
  from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  from nltk import stem
  stemmer=stem.PorterStemmer()


  with open('data.txt')as file:
  while 1:
      line=file.readline().split()
      filtered_words = [w for w in line if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
      documents = [stemmer.stem(line) for line in filtered_words]

      print(documents)


      if not line:
         break
      pass
```

Comment: what are you trying to extract?

Comment: to make a feature vector of the lists

Comment: the output which I got out of the above code is like the following:

Comment: ['sign', 'front', 'steepl', 'church', 'read', 'sunday', 'sermon', 'god', 'prefer', 'particular', 'sport', 'team', 'man', 'pass', 'give', 'sign', 'befuddl', 'look', 'scene', 'fact', 'cartoon', 'current', 'new', 'yorker']
['question', 'good', 'one', 'sinc', 'less', 'news', 'guy', 'check', 'sign', 'might', 'well', 'awar', 'strang', 'one', 'hesit', 'say', 'celesti', 'sport', 'go', 'new']
['york', 'chicago', 'recent', 'week', 'fact', 'supernatur', 'miracl', 'win', 'among', 'encomium', 'infrequ', 'use', 'regard', 'certain', 'yanke', 'postseason', 'triumph', 'true', 'bear']

Comment: but the lists are separated from each other.

Comment: I don't know how to proceed with this code and then apply KNN on it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Scikit-learn's [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) or [TfIdfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer). These can take a list of documents (these are lists of tokens, as in your example) as their input, and return a feature matrix:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(your_list_of_documents)
```

You can find more information in the [Working with Text Data Tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).